# How to animate a widget or the widget icon on my homepage?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, widget, animate.css

I am looking to animate the services widgets or the service widgets icons on the homepage of my theme. I have tried to locate the appropriate files via chrome dev tools without avail. 
So a couple of questions:

1. Is there a better dev tools extension for chrome?
2. How would I locate the appropriate files to animate?

[development website](http://dev.robertsonwebdesigns.com)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try firebug in FireFox.  It complements well with what Chrome shows.  Also a screenshot might help.  Looking at page and not clear what "services widget" is.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! The services area is right below the test slider area.. It has the heading Commercial, Residential and Drain Cleaning